# SBT RabbitMQ Java import not available

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq

I am trying to import the RabbitMQ library into my SBT Scala project, but I cannot use it. SBT builds just fine.

Here is my build.sbt rabbitmq line:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.4.2"
```

and here is my import line in a .scala file:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
```

and here is my compile error:

```
Error:(5, 12) object rabbitmq is not a member of package com
    import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP;
       ^
```

It seems that the import is simply not working, but I have no idea why...

Comment: Are you sure sbt has picked up the added dependency? Did you `reload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with another import. I am using IntelliJ, and SBT importing failed silently with no errors until I used the 'SBT tasks' pane and the 'Refresh all SBT projects' button. Once the offending import was gone, everything works again.